# Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<LM_WebApi.Controllers.Items>

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Having problem on my web api "Cannot implicity convert type IQueryable<> to Generic.List". I'm getting the data from Entity Framework.
When I put ToList() it return this error: **System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<LM_WebApi.Controllers.Items>**

[image]

```
    public IList<Sales_Data> GetSalesData()
    {
        using (var db = new LM_ReportEntities())
        {
            var list = db.OE_Invoiced_BaseProducts.Where(x => x.Year == "2020" && x.Period == 1);
            
            IList<Sales_Data> salesData = new List<Sales_Data>();

            salesData.Add(new Sales_Data { Items = list.Select(x => x.Item_Number).ToList() });
            salesData.Add(new Sales_Data { Periods = list.Select(x => x.Period) });

            return salesData;
        }
    }
```

Here are my class:

```
public class Items
{
    public string Item_No { get; set; }
}

public class Periods
{
    public string Period { get; set; }
}
```

My model:

```
public class Sales_Data
{
    public IList<Items> Items { get; set; } 
    public IList<Periods> Periods { get; set; }
}
```

I want to return the data from Items and Periods as List.

Comment: What type returning this line: `db.OE_Invoiced_BaseProducts.Where(x => x.Year == "2020" && x.Period == 1)`

Comment: @lobstar thats from the Entity. `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery1[LM_DataAccess.OE_Invoiced_BaseProducts]`

Comment: but it got it's signature, you call properties "Year" and "Period"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this in the following way:

```
var list = db.OE_Invoiced_BaseProducts.Where(x => x.Year == "2020" && x.Period == 1).ToList();
```

In the next step, populate the lists of `Items` and `Periods` types from `list` collection.

```
var ItemsList = new List<Items>();
var PeriodsList = new List<Periods>();
foreach (var i in list)
{
    Items item = new Items() { Item_No = i.Item_Number };
    Periods period = new Periods() { Period = i.Period };
    ItemsList.Add(item);
    PeriodsList.Add(period);
}
```

Finally, populate `Sales_Data` model by the above lists.

```
var salesData = new Sales_Data() { Items = ItemsList, Periods = PeriodsList };
```

Comment: @Zach kindly do upvote as well for the useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

change `db.OE_Invoiced_BaseProducts.Where(x => x.Year == "2020" && x.Period == 1)` to `db.OE_Invoiced_BaseProducts.Where(x => x.Year == "2020" && x.Period == 1).ToList()`

Edit:

```
var list = db.OE_Invoiced_BaseProducts.Where(x => x.Year == "2020" && x.Period == 1);
...
salesData.Add(new Sales_Data { Items = list.Select(x => new Items{Item_No = x.Item_Number}).ToList() });
salesData.Add(new Sales_Data { Periods = list.Select(x => new Periods{Periods = x.Period}).ToList() });
```

Comment: How do I put the result to my model that has List. `public IList<Items> Items { get; set; }`
I put like this: 
`IList<Sales_Data> salesData = new List<Sales_Data>();

                salesData.Add(new Sales_Data { Items = list.Select(x => x.Item_Number) });
`
Got an error `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<LM_WebApi.Controllers.Items>'`

Comment: Do you want the Items and Periods in the same Sales_Data object or each in a different ones? Do you need a List of Sales_Data and not just one?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Returned result will be list of two elements, where in first one Periods property is null, and in second one Items property is null too

Comment: True, but this is what the code in the question states. That's why I ask for clarification

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think, you made a mistake in model, change it this way:

```
public class Sales_Data
{
    public string Item_No { get; set; }
    public string Period { get; set; }
}
```

And then change your method like this:

```
public IList<Sales_Data> GetSalesData()
{
    using (var db = new LM_ReportEntities())
    {
        var list = db.OE_Invoiced_BaseProducts.Where(x => x.Year == "2020" && x.Period == 1).ToList();
        
        return (from baseProduct in db.OE_Invoiced_BaseProducts
        where baseProduct.Year = "2020" 
            && baseProduct.Period == 1
        select new Sales_Data()
        {
            Item_No = baseProduct.Item_Number,
            Period = baseProduct.Period
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```